# Button Background Color Change Hovering/PointerOver/MouseEnter - UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

If I type the below part ONLY, I can see that the custom color is applied to entire buttons.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3D8DEB" />       
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
.
.
.

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btn1" ... Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    </Button>
    .
    .
</Grid>
```

However, using the code below, I **CANNOT SEE or CLICK buttons**. (Acts like `Visibility="Collapsed"`)

```
<Style  x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3D8DEB" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                        To="#25326E"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="btn1" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                        To="#25326E"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="btn2" />
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0"
                                        To="Red"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="btn3_ONLY_different" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I want **btn3 to be `Background="Red"`, and ALL THE OTHER buttons to be `Background="#25326E"`** when a mouse is hovering.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why don't you write the two button styles one for red background  and another for all buttons in app.xaml file. and apply the style for specific button using its key in all over the project.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, I'm totally new to both UWP and XAML that I'm not really sure what you mean. Currently I typed all code in `MainPage.xaml` file. Do you mean that I need to write the code in `App.xaml` file instead? Sorry, but can you please be more specific? Is there any link w/ sample code or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `app.xaml` file add the style for btn3

```
  <Style x:Key="StyleForbtn3" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
 <!--you can change background white to any color it will change the background color of the button not Hover color -->

            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
<!--you can set Hover color here -->
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

now add style for all buttons

```
 <Style x:Key="StyleForAllButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <!--you can change background white to any color it will change the background color of the button not Hover color -->

            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#25326E"/>
                                                <!--you can set Hover color here -->
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Now in you mainpage.xaml file add button code and apply style using  a key for button.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource StyleForbtn3}" Content="red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="680,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

<Button Style="{StaticResource StyleForAllButton}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: in the `App.xaml` file, do I write the `<Style...` code inside `<Page.Resource>`???? I get errors for both writing and not writing `<Page.Resource>` :(

Comment: write this inside `<Application.Resources>` tag and close with `</Application.Resources>`

Comment: `<Application.Resources> <Style x:Key="StyleForbtn3" ....> </ Style >  <Style x:Key="StyleForAllButton" ....> </ Style > </Application.Resources> `

Comment: for future style coding you can simply drag and drop the control and right click on the control --> Edit template --> Edit copy --> press ok and now you can see the style will get added to the xaml code and now you can edit this template as how you want :) now you just have to copy that style code and paste it on in your Appx.xaml file and use it in all application by the key :)

Comment: I wonder why all the comments I wrote are deleted except the one with sad emoji... Again thank you so much for your help! You are the BEST!! :D

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to customize the appearance of the `Button`, you need to use the `ContentPresenter` to display the content when you set the `ControlTemplate`.

It should be stated that the `Storyboard` inside `Style` cannot affect other controls. For example, the internal `Storyboard` of `btn1` can only change its own color, and cannot change the color of external `btn2` and `btn3`. If you want to change the color of all buttons when hovering over, you need to use Code-behind and listen for the `Button.PointerEntered` event, or you can use the `VisualStateManager` on Page level.

This is a complete Button custom control template that can be used as a reference

```xml
<Style x:Key="PrimaryButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3D8DEB"/>
    <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="OuterBorderEdge"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#25326E"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When you have a `ContentPresenter`, your control content will show up.

---

If you want to change the color of other buttons while the mouse is hovering, this can be complicated, I suggest you understand this knowledge:

- [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged)
- [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager)

Here is the code to do this:

**ButtonsPage.xaml**

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup.States>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind IsHover, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="btn1.Background" Value="#25326E"/>
                        <Setter Target="btn2.Background" Value="#25326E"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup.States>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Button Content="First" x:Name="btn1"/>
    <Button Content="Second" x:Name="btn2"/>
    <Button Content="Third" x:Name="btn3" PointerEntered="btn3_PointerEntered" PointerExited="btn3_PointerExited"
            Style="{StaticResource PrimaryButtonStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**ButtonsPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class ButtonsPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnProeprtyChnaged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private bool _isHover;

    public bool IsHover
    {
        get => _isHover;
        set 
        { 
            _isHover = value;
            OnProeprtyChnaged();
        }
    }
    public ButtonsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn3_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsHover = true;
    }

    private void btn3_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsHover = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick n detailed answer! Unfortunately though, I get an error `Inaccesible due to protection level` for `PropertyChangedEventHandelr` :(

Comment: Hi, how did you write the code? Did you change the access modifier of `Page` class? Please note that `public` is used instead of `protected`, also note that I used `ButtonsPage` as the name of the page in the example, but if your page is not originally the name, please do not directly modify the name of the Page.

Comment: Hi, since I'm writing the code in MainPage, I used `public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged` and changed the `ButtonsPage()` to `MainPage()`. At least it works with entire button color change when hovering with the complete code you wrote. I'm happy enough :) But I'm now wondering why `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` or `HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"` not working.. (Text in the buttons stays top-left)

Comment: Hi,I am very happy that my answer helped you. Please adjust the position of the text inside the Button by `Padding` property. However, I suggest you learn the [layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels) first so that you can write a custom `ControlTemplate`, such as using `Grid` to create a fully horizontally centered and vertically centered layout.

Comment: I tried adjusting Padding property, but it did not work for me. Digging in a bit, I found out that `ContentPresenter` is the one I was looking for! Still, and again, thank you for your help! :)